# Trying to select from more than one table where field equals value and order by date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `app_user_videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `app_user_photos` (
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo_file_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `photo_thumb` varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photo_caption` varchar(200) DEFAULT 'This Caption',
  PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`),
  KEY `photo_file_name` (`photo_file_name`,`album_id`,`server_created`,`user_id`,`photo_thumb`),
  KEY `photo_caption` (`photo_caption`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1840 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am trying to write a sql statement that selects from both tables WHERE user_id  IN (38,24,56) and then order by date.... I tried to do joins and it selects but I get no data.  I tried to select from both and join on the user_id

Comment: Did you try to use union all ?. this seems like a data problem, can you please provide an script and data example.

Comment: i can't see any problem here.

Comment: 1. `app_user_photos` doesn't have a date. 2. If you're querying on user_id in those two tables you should probably add an index to them and maybe even a foreign key for performance shake.   3. As @JuanRuizdeCastilla stated, data would be very helpful.